# How to lookup for a specific number in a range of sheets and get the position?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with 25 sheets (Named Sheet1, Sheet2 etc).
Each of the sheets has 3 columns. Row 1 of every sheet is blank. Column 1 heading is "Sl No", Column 2 heading is "W Sl No" and Column 3 heading is "D Sl No" and each sheet has 100 to 4000 rows with data as shown below:

Example data in row 2 and 3 of Sheet1:

```
Sl No         W Sl No              D Sl No
```

```
 1              1
```

Example data in row 20 in Sheet5:

```
 1461                                  1362
```

Example data in row 15 in Sheet8:

```
 2599            278
```

So, if "W Sl No" has a serial number, then "D SL No" will be blank and vice versa. That is, for every row, there will be a serial number either against "W Sl No"(Column 2) or "D Sl No"(Column 3).

Now, I want to find the position of a particular serial number, say 79 in Column 2 ("W Sl No"). When the position is found, the serial number (Column 1) against it should be returned.

As I am not sure in which sheet the value exists, I need to search every sheet one by one.

I tried with the following VBA code, but it doesn't work as desired.(The module was inserted in Sheet26)

```
Sub findStuff()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strWhat As String
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFound As String
Dim i As Integer

strWhat = 902
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set rngSearch = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strWhat)
    If Not rngSearch Is Nothing Then
        i = i + 1
        If i = 1 Then
            rngFound = rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
        Else
            rngFound = rngFound & ", " & rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
        End If
    End If
Next ws

MsgBox "'" & strWhat & "' found on the following worksheet(s): " & rngFound & "."
End Sub
```

Currently the code returns the sheet names where the value was found. Now I need the address of the cell that contains the value. Also, the serial number is to be displayed along with the sheet name in a table in Sheet26, instead of showing in a message box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Not sure if it's actually achievable with Excel formula. If you want to loop through all 25 sheets, then I'd suggest you do it using VBA or creating UDF formula. Let us know if you have any trouble with completing your code (i.e. edit your question and paste what you have tried so far).